# Restrict Google from indexing subdomain from Azure CDN services

Tags: web-crawlers, subdomain, robots.txt, images, azure

How can I stop Google from indexing `example.azureedge.net` content? We have the website from last two years but just recently we found out that Google has started to index all the URLs on the azure CDN subdomain website, and most of them have already started ranking. We have been using this subdomain CDN for all our assets. So not sure what caused Google to start indexing all the main URLs all of a sudden.

I have amended `robots.txt` file, and has blocked Google from crawling it but somehow it is still crawling them. If someone know any other way to direct Google straight to custom domain and if anything needed to be changed at Azure dashboard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent azure subdomain indexation](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54444/prevent-azure-subdomain-indexation)

Comment: @MrWhite no unfortunatrely it does not. that article is referring to azure web apps, but we are using azure cdn. although it is helpful but not related to issue mentioend.

Comment: Which CDN SKU are you using? Premium Verizon for example allows you to add rules that redirect traffic if the requesting host matches the raw CDN domain rather than your custom domain...